# How to access bokeh (figure) parameters

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

I would like to change the default tools that holoviews gives after plotting something using bokeh as backend. From what I have read so far I can do this using Hooks but I haven't figure how. The instruction using bokeh should be something like this:

```
plot = figure(tools="pan,wheel_zoom,reset")
```

This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
def hook_test(plot, element):
    plot.state.tools = ["pan,wheel_zoom,reset"]

hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).opts(finalize_hooks=[hook_test])
```

Comment: Hi IsdR94 ! Welcome to SO. Could you try and then add the code to question if it doesn't work?

Comment: sure! let me edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass a list of tool names as strings or as tool object instances to the `.opts` method. One tricky aspect is that the list of tools only extends the default set, and if you want to replace it, you'll need to separately remove the default_tools:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.Curve([1, 2, 3]).opts(tools=['pan','wheel_zoom','reset'], default_tools=[])
```

[image: screenshot]